# Find the MLE for ordered pairs of random variables

Tags: maximum-likelihood

I'm struggling with finding the MLEs for $\pi_{ij}$ in the following problem:

The ordered pairs of random variables is such that $P((X_k,Y_k)=(i,j))=\pi _{ij}$ where $\pi _{ij}=\alpha_i \beta_j$ for $i=1,2,...,r$ and $j=1,2,...,c$ with $\sum \alpha_i=1$ and $\sum \beta_i=1$ The frequency of each $(i,j)$ is $n_{ij}$.

I recognise that this means $X$ and $Y$ are independent and tried to find the MLE the usual way:

$l(\pi_{ij};x)=\sum_i \sum_j n_{ij}(log(\alpha_i) +log(\beta_j))$

If I then differentiate w.r.t.any of the alphas or betas I get a contradiction that $n_{ij}/\alpha_i=0$ so I can't find the probabilities... How do I proceed? Thanks in advance for your help!

The second part of the question is to find the MLEs but this time without the restriction of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. How would you go about this? Wont' the same thing happen with the probabilities as this time?

Comment: You obtained a contradiction because you didn't account for the constraints on the sums of the alphas and the betas.  Working this problem for the case $c=1$ and $r=2$ (where there is effectively just one parameter) ought to reveal the problem and suggest how to cope with it.

Answer (score 0):

Partially answered in comments:

> You obtained a contradiction because you didn't account for the
> constraints on the sums of the alphas and the betas.  Working this
> problem for the case $c=1$ and $r=2$ (where there is effectively just
> one parameter) ought to reveal the problem and suggest how to cope
> with it.

- whuber